# How to copy a Visual Studio database unit test

Tags: database, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests for stored procedures in VSTE for Database Professionals, and want to copy some already existing test cases that only need to be modified in a few places. Manually re-creating them would be very tedious. I couldn't find a solution either on the web or in books. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not easy but here is the best method that I've found.

This method assumes that each test file contains 1 or more tests *targeting the same database object*. (Ex: PeopleTest.cs runs tests against the People table; spGetPeopleTest.cs targets stored procedure spGetPeople...) This makes the replace-all easier (for example you'd copy a PeopleTest.cs file and rename all "People" references to "Tasks").

1. In Solution Explorer, copy-paste the unit test file.  Rename the new file.
2. Right-click the new file and select View Code to open the C#/VB code file.
3. Perform a Replace All in the code file.  For example if the original test referenced a Tasks table and you want your new test to reference a People table, replace "Tasks" with "People".
4. In Solution Explorer, expand the new test file to expose the .resx file.  (This is where the SQL code is stored.)  Right-click the .resx file, select Open With, then select XML Editor.
5. Perform the same Replace All in this file.
6. Save all, then re-open the test in the designer and your new test is ready to go.

Comment: Any options if you want to include multiple tests per file, instead of one test == one file?

Comment: This method will work if the file contains multiple tests, as long as each test within the file targets the same database object. That's simply to make the replace-all steps easier. (I edited my answer to make this clearer.)